# Coincidence summing in gamma spectrum

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, gamma-rays

Question on coincidence summing here. I've been reading about the coincidence summing effect when a radionuclide has two energy levels that decay to another state in rapid succession.

There is also the effect, which I've seen referred to as "random summing", when two different gammas, from two different radionuclides, strike the detector either at the same time or in quick succession.

Both of these things result in the same effect. My question is really about how much I need to factor these two effects in when analysing a spectrum?

If, for example, I observe a peak on my spectrum at 691KeV and can't find an appropriate candidate isotope, is it appropriate to assume it to be a result of coincidence/random summing?

If I do attribute the peak to the result of coincidence/random summing, is there any way to determine approximately what height the peaks should be at the energy levels which are being summed? Bigger than the summed peak? Smaller?

Any and all help/advice on the topic is appreciated.

Comment: P.s. I've since realized that 691KeV is the energy level for (n,n') in Ge-72, but the question still stands.

Comment: The probability for random summing should depend on the count rate, the relative line amplitude should therefor depend on that in a predictable fashion (real lines scale proportional to the total count rate, random summing lines with the square). In case of coincidence summing the two lines that make up the total energy of the fake line should also show up strongly.